# how group the result based on some condition into concatenated results

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i want to `group` my `results` based on `timestamp`.

**Demo** : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab315b/1

for example if `date` is `14` having 3 results then i want my **output** like below

```
+                                  results                                                         +
|                                                                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   <td> 14</td><td>project name1</td><td><p>project desc 1</p></td><td>created at 1</td>          |                                                                                                  
|    <td> 13</td><td>project name2</td><td><p>project desc 2</p></td><td>created at 2</td>
|    <td> 12</td><td>project name3</td><td><p>project desc 3</p></td><td>created at 2</td>
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                other results of same date like 13                               |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**ACCORDING TO BELOW IMAGE AND QUERY:**

[image]

**here i have put my for execution:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab315b/1

Please help me 
Thanks in Advance !!!!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM work_desc GROUP BY CAST(created_at AS DATE) ORDER BY created_at DESC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Group_concat` to concatenate multiple lines here. Something like

```
SELECT created_at, Group_concat(project_desc, ' ') FROM work_desc 
Group By CAST(created_at AS DATE)
ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

its output looks like

```
created_at  Group_concat(project_desc, ' ')
2017-11-14T10:18:54Z    this my first day report employeee 2222 ,this my first day report employeee 33333 ,this my first day report employeee 44444
2017-11-12T18:30:00Z    this my yesterday day report employeee 2222 ,this my yesterday day report employeee 33333
```

You can work out a bit to generate the output you are looking for I believe.

**EDIT**

I believe this returns the output you are looking for

```
SELECT concat(Group_concat(concat('<tr><td>', project_name, 
                           '</td><td>', project_desc, '</td>') 
                    SEPARATOR '</tr>'), '</tr>') 
FROM work_desc GROUP BY CAST(created_at AS DATE) 
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You might also want to use `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet` before the query. GROUP_CONCAT's max length defaults to 1024 bytes

Comment: @codeomnitrix, still i'm unable to get my desired `result`, i have tried your `query` but i'm getting `unexpected` `results`. as i don't have much knowledge please help me, i have created table online please try http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab315b/2

Comment: @GouthamGgs try the edited query and put `<p>` and other fields as and when required in concat. I think you should be able to produce your expected output easily